# Comparing date string formatted as '6012017' to date format '06-01-2017'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that both have a date column. One is stored as nvarchar, and its formatted as '6012017'. The other is stored as a date, and appears as '06-01-2017'.

I need to be able to link up the tables by matching dates. I've tried casting and converting the nvarchar to a date, which doesn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So does that mean dec/nov will present as 8 characters instead of 7? ex: `'12012017'`

Comment: Anyone who formats dates like that is playing with fire. Did we learn nothing from Y2K? Also is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) so hard? `YYYY-MM-DD` is not only unambiguous, it's easily sorted.

Comment: @JacobH, thats correct.

Answer (score 4):

This should convert your date column to a date accounting for leading '0':

```
CONVERT(DATE, STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('0' + [DateColumn], 8), 5, 0, '-'), 3, 0, '-'))
```

You might consider making this into persisted computed column or scalar function if you do this often.

As noted in comments below, if you ever need to account for "mm-dd-yyyy" or "dd-mm-yyyy", you can use a third parameter to tell `CONVERT` how to interpret. For your example having "mddyyyy" as original input, this would need style "110" so it matches to the string "mm-dd-yyyy".

```
CONVERT(DATE, STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('0' + [DateColumn], 8), 5, 0, '-'), 3, 0, '-'), 110)
```

For more styles: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Comment: Careful, dates with `-` as a separator are *probably* DD-MM-YYYY. Your code *probably* (I believe it depends on server settings) interprets it as MM-DD-YYYY.

Comment: Yes, definitely depends on collation and convention. I assumed those based on output shared in OP, but to your point, that is a factor in other scenarios.

Comment: To assist @hvd: Ever use `CONVERT()` with the third parameter to get a definit format...

Comment: @hvd: Actually dashes are more typically employed with the MM-DD-YYYY pattern. Dates that precede with the day usually use periods: `dd.MM.YYYY`.

Comment: @Shnugo Either that, or convert to one of the unambiguous date formats that works regardless of server settings.

Comment: @ChrisPratt For day-first formats, all separators are used. `/`, `-`, `.`. Month-first formats almost universally use `/` as separators.

Comment: Well, all separators are valid for either way. And, I've seen dates done both ways in all kinds of variations, but if we're talking about most common, I stand by my original statement. Month-first does often use `/` but `-` is just as common, if not more.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking ISO? (YYYY-MM-DD). That universally uses dashes, but it's not the same flip around.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I now checked both Wikipedia (yeah, I know) and Microsoft Windows's list of date formats per country. Both show `mm/dd/yyyy`, `dd/mm/yyyy`, `dd-mm-yyyy` and `dd.mm.yyyy` in multiple locations (and some other formats too), neither shows `mm-dd-yyyy` used anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

First you can format the string-formatted datetime to valid `DateTime` using an aproach such as below:

```
DECLARE @i NVARCHAR(MAX) = '6012017'
set @i =  right(REPLICATE('0',8)+@i,8)

declare @date datetime
Set @date = (select DATEFROMPARTS(SUBSTRING(@i,5,4),SUBSTRING(@i,3,2),SUBSTRING(@i,1,2)))

Select @date
```

Now, what you have inside `@date` is a valid `DateTime` value, which you can use it for your comparison purposes

**Note:** You can write the whole query inside one `SELECT` query as below. What is returned by `SELECT` is a valid `DateTime` value

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(
            SUBSTRING(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',8)+'6012017',8),5,4),
            SUBSTRING(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',8)+'6012017',8),3,2),
            SUBSTRING(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',8)+'6012017',8),1,2))
```

Even for the `06-01-2017` you can follow the same approach as below:

```
Select DATEFROMPARTS(
            SUBSTRING(REPLACE('06-01-2017','-','') ,5,4),
            SUBSTRING(REPLACE('06-01-2017','-','') ,3,2),
            SUBSTRING(REPLACE('06-01-2017','-','') ,1,2))
```

Finally if you execute the following query, you will notice that both dates are equal and the comparison procedure is done successfully!

```
Select DateDiff(Day,
                DATEFROMPARTS(
                    SUBSTRING(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',8)+'6012017',8),5,4),
                    SUBSTRING(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',8)+'6012017',8),3,2),
                    SUBSTRING(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0',8)+'6012017',8),1,2)), 
                DATEFROMPARTS(
                    SUBSTRING(REPLACE('06-01-2017','-','') ,5,4),
                    SUBSTRING(REPLACE('06-01-2017','-','') ,3,2),
                    SUBSTRING(REPLACE('06-01-2017','-','') ,1,2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue this is easiest. It's shorter, has less nesting, it uses functions that don't require remembering any weird parameters, and it eliminates the worries about date formats and separators.

```
select cast(right(dt, 4) + left(right('0' + dt, 8), 4) as date);
```

> The advantage in using the ISO 8601 format is that it is an
>   international standard with unambiguous specification. Also, this
>   format is not affected by the SET DATEFORMAT or SET LANGUAGE setting.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql

There are limitations on using only deterministic functions in some scenarios  but I'm not sure whether this gets around that restriction.